# How can I run a ruby script right after the server starts in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two ruby scripts that need to be running while the server is.

Currently I am running them separately using detached screens, but I would like to launch them at the same time the rails server is starting.

How can I integrate them so that I can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Foreman gem? It will allow you to create a simple file (Procfile) where you can specify all the process that should be started simultaneously.

I usually create a file named Procfile.dev in the project's root, that would look like for example:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin start -p 4000
mail: mailcatcher -f
your_script: instructions
```

Then you start your Rails app as:

```
foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

With that command, Foreman will execute all the processes on the file.

You should install the gem locally and not in the Gemfile.

[Foreman Gem](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)

Comment: It looks promising, I forgot to mention that this scripts must keep running while the server is running, they do not stop when called, will foreman allow this behavior?

Comment: What kind of script is it?

Comment: It is an mqtt subscriber that uses the `ruby-mqtt` gem. Basically it listens for mqtt protocol publishers and when one is emitted with the topic the subscriber is programmed to listen for it executes some code that interacts with the rails app.

Comment: I think it should work, but you should test it installing the gem and creating the Procfile. Shouldn't take took long to set up.

Comment: This is the correct answer, worked like a charm, marking as correct and upvoting.